# Allow maximum of 10 Emails in Jquery Validation with each comma separated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

how to allow and validate only 10 emails or minimum with each comma separated. It should allow only 10 emails or minimum and each emails are comma separated.Now i can only validate each emails separated by commas

```
    <form method="post" action="" id="add_engagement" name="add_engagement" class="form-horizontal">
<tr><td>Email Recipients</td>
    <td><textarea name="email_recipients"  id="email_recipients" >{$Notification.email_recipients}</textarea><br/><span style="color:red">*</span>Note: Separated by commas(,)</td>
</tr>
 <input type="submit" class="post_button" id="edit_notification" value="Update" name="edit_notification" /></td></tr>
</form>


<script>    
$(function(){
$('#edit_notification').one('click', function () {
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
      debug: true,
      success: "valid"
    });
$.validator.addMethod('multiEmails', function(value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        var valid = true;

        $.each($.trim(value).replace(/,$/, '').split(','), $.proxy(function (index, email) {
            if (!$.validator.methods.email.call(this, $.trim(email), element)) {
                valid = false;
            }
        }, this));

        return valid; 
        }
    }, 'One or more email addresses are invalid');

$("#add_engagement").validate({

    rules: {

        email_recipients: {
                required: true,
                multiEmails:true,

            },  
        },
        messages: {

        email_recipients: {
        required: "Please enter email",

        },
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
    },
});<script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add counter:

```
var ec = 0;
$.each($.trim(value).replace(/,$/, '').split(','), $.proxy(function (index, email) {
    ec++;
    if (!$.validator.methods.email.call(this, $.trim(email), element)) {
        valid = false;
    }
}, this));
if (ec<1 || ec>10) valid = false;
```

Or you can add another validation rule on the amount of e-mail addresses, with a separate error message.